# Running time analysis of algorithm with log

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I have the following algorithm pseudocode here:

```
for (j = 2 to n){
 k=1
 while (k<j^2) {
  k=2*k
 }
}
```

The method I learned just analyzes it line by line, so line 1 I can see that it runs n-2 times, and line 2 runes n-1 times.

What confuses me here is the while loop, I'm not too sure how to approach it. I think it runs **log( j<sup>2</sup> ) times** on its own, so I get something like **(n-1) * log( j<sup>2</sup> )** for line 3? But aren't we supposed to have everything in terms of n?

Comment: Try to formalize the counting of the iterations of the while loop as a mathematical series.

Comment: The inner loop will run like this: `1 + 4 + 9 +16 +25 + 36` which means quadractic factor so plug in n and do you see how many times it executes? It not logN, if it was logN it was `N/2`.

Answer (score 0):

The inner while loop is`Theta(log j^2) = Theta(2 log j) = Theta(log j)`.

So total runtime is `Theta(2(log 2 + log 3 + ... + log n))` = `Theta(n log n)`